# Calculating interest in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Funcional Programming is very new to me and can't seem to understand how to use a function as an argument for another function. finalvalue is supposed to calculate the final value after a period, and finalvalue2 after 2 periods.

```
interest :: Float -> Float -> Float
interest capital rate = capital * rate * 0.01

finalvalue :: Float -> Float -> Float
finalvalue capital rate = capital + interest capital rate

finalvalue2 :: Float -> Float -> Float
finalvalue2 capital rate = finalvalue capital rate + interest finalvalue capital rate rate
```

I get this:

```
Couldn't match expected type `Float'
       against inferred type `Float -> Float -> Float'
In the first argument of `interest', namely `finalvalue'
In the second argument of `(+)', namely
    `interest finalvalue capital rate rate'
In the expression:
      finalvalue capital rate + interest finalvalue capital rate rate
```

I'm sure I'm missing a basic point here but I just can't find out what it is.

Comment: Count the number of arguments you declare for `interest` and the number of arguments you apply to it in `finalvalue2`. Do you see what's wrong?

Comment: @Nick: `$` won't work here because the function call is not the last argument.

Comment: Well it would work if he swapped the order of the arguments round in the interest function. But yes, I agree, see my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
interest finalvalue capital rate rate
```

Here you're calling `interest` with four arguments, the first of which is a function. Since `interest`'s first argument needs to be a Float, not a function, you get the error message you do.

What you probably intended to write was `interest (finalvalue capital rate) rate`, which calls `interest` with two floats, the first of which is the result of calling `finalvalue` with `capital` and `rate` as arguments.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't know i was supposed to use brackets like that. problem solved.

Answer (score 4):

You just need some parentheses, no?

```
finalvalue2 :: Float -> Float -> Float
finalvalue2 capital rate = 
   finalvalue capital rate + interest (finalvalue capital rate) rate
```

In

```
finalvalue2 :: Float -> Float -> Float
finalvalue2 capital rate = 
   finalvalue capital rate + interest finalvalue capital rate rate
                                      ^^^^^^^^^^
```

the compiler is taking the marked use of `finalvalue`, by itself, to be the first argument of `interest`, as if it were `3.23`, but of course it can't make sense of that.  (It is a good idea to look at the exact position mentioned by the error statement, which in this case points to the place I marked.)

Answer (score 1):

```
finalvalue2              :: Float -> Float -> Float
finalvalue2 capital rate = finalvalue capital rate + interest (finalvalue capital rate) rate
```